# Maven 2 & 3 differences on dependency:analyze with cycle

Tags: maven, circular-dependency, dependency-analysis

Here's the dependency tree I'm using:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PA 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ PA ---
[INFO] myTest:PA:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- PC:PC:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- myTest:PA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

As you can see, there's a cycle :

```
PA > PC > PA
```

Using maven 2.2.1:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - myTest:PA:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:analyze]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] No dependency problems found
```

Using maven 3.3.3:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PA 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) @ PA ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    myTest:PA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

The analyze using maven 3 wants me to add PA as a dependency to PA, to itself. Is it possible to have the same behavior as maven 2 using maven 3?

Comment: To be clear there is no cycle, cause the last dependency has a different version. Apart from that it looks wrong that you have two versions of the same artifact `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT` ...

Comment: There's something wrong in your design. Why is an artifact depending on itself?

Comment: It doesn't, PA depends on PC and PC depends on PA

Comment: That's the same. PA and PC should be one...

Comment: This is not a question about the design. I agree that you should avoid cycles. The question is about the behavior difference between maven 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the workaround I'm using to have the same result as Maven 2 using Maven 3:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <ignoredDependencies>
                        <ignoredDependencie>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}::</ignoredDependencie>
                    </ignoredDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```